# Android Java - Get JSON Value

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on an android app and I'm trying to get the value of UPC in this JSON format.. but having trouble.. I'm able to get allergens values using:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray  jsonData = jObj.getJSONArray("allergens");
```

but for some reason I can't seem to get the UPC value.. any help would be greatly appreciated!

JSON:

```
{
"upc": "028400071932",
"product_name": "CRUNCHY CHEESE",
"canStoreName": "false",
"processedIngredients": "",
"allergens": [{
    "allergen_name": "Cereals",
    "allergen_value": 2,
    "allergen_red_ingredients": "CORN, Corn, Maltodextrin, CORN MEAL, ENRICHED CORN MEAL",
    "allergen_yellow_ingredients": "VEGETABLE OIL, CITRIC ACID, MONOSODIUM GLUTAMATE, Natural and Artificial Flavors"
}, {
    "allergen_name": "Shellfish",
    "allergen_value": 0,
    "allergen_red_ingredients": "",
    "allergen_yellow_ingredients": ""
}],
"ingredients": "ENRICHED CORN MEAL (CORN MEAL, FERROUS SULFATE, NIACIN, THIAMIN MONONITRATE, RIBOFLAVIN, AND FOLIC ACID), VEGETABLE OIL (CORN, SOYBEAN CANOLA, AND/OR SUNFLOWER OIL), WHEY, CHEDDAR CHEESE (MILK, CHEESE CULTURES, SALT, ENZYMES), SALT, SEA MINERALS(CALCIUM CARBONATE AND MAGNESIUM CARBONATE), MALTODEXTRIN (MADE FROM CORN), WHEY PROTEIN CONCENTRATE, MONOSODIUM GLUTAMATE, NATURAL AND ARTIFICIAL FLAVORS LACTIC ACID, CITRIC ACID, AND ARTIFICIAL COLOR (YELLOW 6, YELLOW 5)."
}
```

Comment: So, where is the code that tries to get the upc value? And what happens precisely when executing this code?

Comment: that's the problem.. I don't have the code.. I tried a few different things but always got the error: ".string cannot be converted to JSONOBject"

Comment: So, show us the code you tried and the exact and complete error you got, so that we can explain you why it's wrong and how to fix it. Giving you a solution that you won't understand won't make you learn anything.

Comment: I've tried the following:
String upc = jObj.getString("upc"); 
Object aObj = jObj.get("upc");
JSONObject.get("upc");
Get:
11-24 11:08:01.120: W/System.err(1394): org.json.JSONException: No value for upc

Comment: @user3028945, just curious, what API are you using to get the allergen information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ // json object node
"upc": "028400071932",// string
```

`{` represents json object node

`[` represents json array node

So use

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
String value = jObj.getString("upc");
```

Another example

```
"allergens": [ // jsonarray allergens
    {          // json object 
    "allergen_name": "Cereals", // string
```

So to get allergen_name

```
JSONArray  jsonData = jObj.getJSONArray("allergens");
for(int i=0;i<jsonData.length();i++)
{
     JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jsonData.get(i);
     String allergenname = jb.getString("allergen_name");  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Raghunandan.. I'm a PHP developer giving Java a shot for the first time and you have been more than helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String value = jObj.getString("upc");
```

Comment: Thanks.. just tried that and getting the error:

11-24 11:09:16.242: W/System.err(1469): org.json.JSONException: Value 028400071932 at upc of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: this is wrong. `{` represetns json objectnode and this 
"upc": "028400071932", is a string

Comment: @user3028945  use `String value = jObj.getString("upc");`

Comment: wow... that was it! thanks a lot  Raghunandan! If you want to add that as an answer I will select you.. thanks again!

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer for future references.